# Solubility of fluoroalkanes

Tags: organic-chemistry, halides

I know haloalkanes generally aren't soluble in water due to their inability to form hydrogen bonds in water, despite being moderately polar. I was wondering why this is the case with fluoroalkanes too as fluorine is quiet capable of forming H bonds.
Someone suggested to me that fluorine atoms bonded to carbon atoms cannot form hydrogen bonds but this logic seems flawed. Take the case of chloral hydrate. If chlorine can do it, why not fluorine? Please correct me if I'm wrong.